# Why am I getting a TypeError during ML Model initialisation?

Tags: python

I am running a deep learning project at https://github.com/hyangwinter/flownet3d_pytorch. There are some problems during operation, and I don't know how to solve them.

The error is as follows：

```
Namespace(batch_size=64, cycle=False, dataset='SceneflowDataset', dataset_path='data/data_processed_maxcut_35_20k_2k_8192/', dropout=0.5, emb_dims=512, epochs=250, eval=False, exp_name='flownet3d', gaussian_noise=False, lr=0.001, model='flownet', model_path='', momentum=0.9, no_cuda=False, num_points=2048, seed=1234, test_batch_size=32, unseen=False, use_sgd=False)
    train :  20006
    test :  2007
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 282, in <module>
        main()
    File "main.py", line 254, in main
        net = FlowNet3D(args).cuda()
    File "/home/ubuntu/project/flownet3d_pytorch/model.py", line 13, in __init__
        self.sa1 = PointNetSetAbstraction(npoint=1024, radius=0.5, nsample=16, in_channel=3, mlp=[32,32,64], group_all=False)
    File "/home/ubuntu/project/flownet3d_pytorch/util.py", line 225, in __init__
        for out_channel in mlp2:
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
```

My code:

```
class FlowNet3D(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,args):
        super(FlowNet3D,self).__init__()

        self.sa1 = PointNetSetAbstraction(npoint=1024, radius=0.5, nsample=16, in_channel=3, mlp=[32,32,64], group_all=False)
        self.sa2 = PointNetSetAbstraction(npoint=256, radius=1.0, nsample=16, in_channel=64, mlp=[64, 64, 128], group_all=False)
        self.sa3 = PointNetSetAbstraction(npoint=64, radius=2.0, nsample=8, in_channel=128, mlp=[128, 128, 256], group_all=False)
        self.sa4 = PointNetSetAbstraction(npoint=16, radius=4.0, nsample=8, in_channel=256, mlp=[256,256,512], group_all=False)
    
        self.fe_layer = FlowEmbedding(radius=10.0, nsample=64, in_channel = 128, mlp=[128, 128, 128], pooling='max', corr_func='concat')
    
        self.su1 = PointNetSetUpConv(nsample=8, radius=2.4, f1_channel = 256, f2_channel = 512, mlp=[], mlp2=[256, 256])
        self.su2 = PointNetSetUpConv(nsample=8, radius=1.2, f1_channel = 128+128, f2_channel = 256, mlp=[128, 128, 256], mlp2=[256])
        self.su3 = PointNetSetUpConv(nsample=8, radius=0.6, f1_channel = 64, f2_channel = 256, mlp=[128, 128, 256], mlp2=[256])
        self.fp = PointNetFeaturePropogation(in_channel = 256+3, mlp = [256, 256])
    
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(256, 128, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.conv2=nn.Conv1d(128, 3, kernel_size=1, bias=True)
    
    def forward(self, pc1, pc2, feature1, feature2):
        l1_pc1, l1_feature1 = self.sa1(pc1, feature1)
        l2_pc1, l2_feature1 = self.sa2(l1_pc1, l1_feature1)
    
        l1_pc2, l1_feature2 = self.sa1(pc2, feature2)
        l2_pc2, l2_feature2 = self.sa2(l1_pc2, l1_feature2)
    
        _, l2_feature1_new = self.fe_layer(l2_pc1, l2_pc2, l2_feature1, l2_feature2)

        l3_pc1, l3_feature1 = self.sa3(l2_pc1, l2_feature1_new)
        l4_pc1, l4_feature1 = self.sa4(l3_pc1, l3_feature1)
    
        l3_fnew1 = self.su1(l3_pc1, l4_pc1, l3_feature1, l4_feature1)
        l2_fnew1 = self.su2(l2_pc1, l3_pc1, torch.cat([l2_feature1, l2_feature1_new], dim=1), l3_fnew1)
        l1_fnew1 = self.su3(l1_pc1, l2_pc1, l1_feature1, l2_fnew1)
        l0_fnew1 = self.fp(pc1, l1_pc1, feature1, l1_fnew1)
    
        x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(l0_fnew1)))
        sf = self.conv2(x)
        return sf

class PointNetSetAbstraction(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, npoint, radius, nsample, in_channel, mlp, mlp2 = None, group_all = False):
        super(PointNetSetAbstraction, self).__init__()
        self.npoint = npoint
        self.radius = radius
        self.nsample = nsample
        self.group_all = group_all
        self.mlp_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.mlp_bns = nn.ModuleList()
        self.mlp2_convs = nn.ModuleList()
        last_channel = in_channel+3
        for out_channel in mlp:
            self.mlp_convs.append(nn.Conv2d(last_channel, out_channel, 1, bias = False))
            self.mlp_bns.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channel))
            last_channel = out_channel
        for out_channel in mlp2:
            self.mlp2_convs.append(nn.Sequential(nn.Conv1d(last_channel, out_channel, 1, bias=False),
                                                nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channel)))
            last_channel = out_channel
        if group_all:
            self.queryandgroup = pointutils.GroupAll()
        else:
            self.queryandgroup = pointutils.QueryAndGroup(radius, nsample)
    def forward(self, xyz, points):
        """
        Input:
            xyz: input points position data, [B, C, N]
            points: input points data, [B, D, N]
        Return:
            new_xyz: sampled points position data, [B, S, C]
            new_points_concat: sample points feature data, [B, S, D']
        """
        device = xyz.device
        B, C, N = xyz.shape
        xyz_t = xyz.permute(0, 2, 1).contiguous()
        # if points is not None:
        #     points = points.permute(0, 2, 1).contiguous()

        if self.group_all == False:
            fps_idx = pointutils.furthest_point_sample(xyz_t, self.npoint)  # [B, N]
            new_xyz = pointutils.gather_operation(xyz, fps_idx)  # [B, C, N]
        else:
            new_xyz = xyz
        new_points = self.queryandgroup(xyz_t, new_xyz.transpose(2, 1).contiguous(), points) # [B, 3+C, N, S]
    
        # new_xyz: sampled points position data, [B, C, npoint]
        # new_points: sampled points data, [B, C+D, npoint, nsample]
        for i, conv in enumerate(self.mlp_convs):
            bn = self.mlp_bns[i]
            new_points =  F.relu(bn(conv(new_points)))

        new_points = torch.max(new_points, -1)[0]

        for i, conv in enumerate(self.mlp2_convs):
            new_points = F.relu(conv(new_points))
        return new_xyz, new_points`
```

I noticed that the mlp2 parameter is set to NONE but I don't know how to solve it. In the source code implementation, this parameter is also NONE

Comment: your code sample is broken, please try to fix it for better reproducibility

Answer (score 1):

Since your `self.sa1` do not have parameters named `mlp2`, it will use the default one, `None` as you defined in

```
class PointNetSetAbstraction(nn.Module): 
    def init(self, npoint, radius, nsample, in_channel, mlp, mlp2 = None, group_all = False):
```

And of cause `None` is not iterable, to solve this, you can just add a `if`-condition before the `for`-loop. Otherwise, you can also just pass `mlp2=[]` as you already done for `self.su1`.

Comment: correct explanation +1. But I think skipping the for-loop will not make the code work, as there won't be any layer initialization.

Comment: While we skip the init using:
`
if mlp2:
    for ...

...
`
the `mlp2_convs` will still be a empty `nn.ModuleList` which is ok to iterate over. So there should bo no problem.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I used the if condition to judge whether mlp2 is None to decide whether to initialize mlp2_convs. The code runs normally and I get the same result as the author. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in your question, `mlp2` is set to `None` in the function call. When trying to iterate over `mlp2` with

```
for out_channel in mlp2:
```

the code corectly throws a `TypeError`.

It is hard to understand what you are trying to do, especially because `mlp2` is not a good variable name (what even should that be?). From the context of your code I would assume that `mpl2` is a list that holds the **sizes of your layers**. You might try something like:

```
mlp2 = [16,16,16,16]
```

This will initialize the Model to have layers of size 16 (if the rest of the code is working).